# Defining a function with a bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a question that asks:

S =  ={(1,2,…,) : ∈ℕ, ≠0}

S is the set of all finite ordered n-tuples of nonnegative integers where the last coordinate is not 0

the question asks to find a bijection $f: S\to Z^{+}$

I have so far identified that seeing as $n$ is a positive integer, it had a unique prime factorisation ie n = ${p_{1}^{a_1}, p_2^{a_2},...,p_k^{a_k}}$
this pattern is very similar to the given set.

I'm just a little bit stuck as to how to find a bijection. Could someone please point me in the right direction :)

Comment: You should clarify... Someone asked a moment ago, but the comment is now deleted.  How many elements are in your set $S$?  Finitely many or infinitely many?  The dots after $a_n$ were added by another user and were not present in your original post.  Are you merely looking for an *injection* or are you truly looking for a **bi**jection?  Note that there exists a bijection between two sets if and only if they are of the same cardinality (*by definition*) and a finite set is certainly not in bijection with an infinite set.

Comment: This is a *really* weirdly written problem.  There's no indication that $S$ is infinite and the stipulation that $a_n \ne 0$ but nothing about the others is strange.  Could you write out *exactly* what the problem actually says.

Comment: There is also the question of whether or not $a_1,a_2,\dots$ are all unique values.  If not, then consider the case of $a_1=a_2=x$.  What would be $f(x)$?  If you were to use the answers below, you would say $f(a_1)=1$ but you would say $f(a_2)=2$... but since $a_1=a_2$ these should have been equal results but they aren't and so the definitions used below fail to even be functions.

Comment: I looked at the original post and it was $S= a_1, a_2, .... a_n$ with a stipulation that $a_n\ne 0$ which indicates a finite list and... well it's weird.  The stipulation that $a_n\ne 0$ (but $a_{i< n}$ might be) make me wonder if the problem isn't find bijection between $\mathbb Z^+$ and all such lists.  (But that would suggest each $a_i$ have a max value... such as $a_i = 0,1,2....9$).

Comment: Given the context of the problem and the context of your attempt, is it possible that you meant to write $S=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)~:~n\in\Bbb N,~a_n\neq 0,~a_i\in\Bbb N\}$ where the elements of $S$ are finite length tuples of arbitrary length whose final entry is always nonzero?  (*where the natural bijection would be the one you noticed using prime factorization of the integers*)

Comment: @JMoravitz  Are you suggesting that maybe the question is to prove there is a bijection from $\mathbb N^n\to \mathbb N$.  That's a reasonable interpretation but the requirement that $a_n$ be non-zero is odd.  I was think the were interpretting the idea that if the $a_i$ represent digits they could map to $n$ digit numbers (but that'd require $0\le a_i \le 9$).  But this is a strange question, isn't it? [Oh, never mind... I see what you are getting at!... but what would map to $1$?]

Comment: I'm really confused now but i have edited the question to exactly how it is given to me

Comment: @fleablood No, I was suggesting something closer to that there be a bijection from $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Bbb N^n\to\Bbb N$ but with the stipulation that we not consider tuples with trailing zeroes to make the bijection easier, that way we don't say for instance $24=2^3\cdot 3^1$ as well as $2^3\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^0$ as well as $2^3\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^0\cdot 7^0$ etc...

Comment: @fleablood as for what would map to $1$, that would be the $0$-tuple

Comment: @JMoravitz how would i use the prime factorisation to define a function?

Comment: Yeah.  kudos to JMoravitz for sussing this out.  Take JMoravitz hint.  For instance the tuple $(5,0,1,0,3)\mapsto 2^5*5^1*11^3=212960$.  And the tuple $(0,1)\mapsto 3^1=3$.  But what maps to $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz.  Is $0\in \mathbb N$ and is $()\in S$?  I suppose they could be.  ... But what maps to $0$ then?  .... Or we could do $0\not \in \mathbb N$ and $(a_1,a_2,....,a_n)\mapsto p_1^{a_1}..p_n^{a_n} - 1$.....

Comment: I would say in this context it makes the most sense to have $0\in\Bbb N$ and $()\in S$, absolutely.  As for what maps to $0$, nothing does, but that isn't a problem because we are trying to find a bijection to $\Bbb Z^+$

Comment: @JMoravitz  I understand the relationship now thank you! I am just still a bit uncertain as to how to write this using the function notation

Comment: can i say $f(a_{1} , _2,...,_)$ = $p_{1}^{a_1} *p_{2}^{a_2}...*p_{n}^{a_n}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the problem has been corrected to include the correct statement, your initial impressions and approach were exactly correct.

Let $S=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)~:~n\in\Bbb N,~a_i\in\Bbb N,~a_n\neq 0\}$ be the set of all tuples of varying finite length (*including zero!*) whose entries are all natural numbers and whose final entry (*if it exists*) is nonzero.

Before continuing on, I need to stress the importance of notation.  Here, we have [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).  We have something along the lines of $\{~~\text{object}~~:~~\text{rules}~~\}$.  Every element in the set looks like "$\text{object}$" and every possible object will be in the set that satisfy the collection of "$\text{rules}$."  In your case, again, each element in your set looks like $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and is an $n$-tuple for some $n$.

This is *very* different than the set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ where each element in the set is just a number.  Each element in your actual set is a tuple of numbers.

Now, this ranges over all possible ways to fill in each variable value, including $n$ and including each value of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ etc...  Including here where $n=0$ in which case all you are left with is the $0$-tuple ().

---

Now, suppose we have an $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and we wish to map this to a unique integer, one who will not have anything else map to it.  We can do this by mapping $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\mapsto \prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$ where $p_i$ represents the $i$'th prime number.

Alternatively written, we have $f((a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n))=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$

Notice a few things.  First, we might be concerned about whether or not $1$ has a preimage.  It does!  It will be the $0$-tuple mentioned earlier.  We would have $f(())$ would result in the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

Now... the question is whether or not this function is truly a bijection.  That is precisely the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  I will not attempt to prove it here, but the fundamental theorem of arithmetic essentially says that yes, there is indeed going to be a bijection here, noting a few key details that any such unique factorization of a number will have a unique largest appearing prime factor, hence why we required that $a_n\neq 0$, precisely to avoid having situations like $(3,1)$ mapping to the same outcome as $(3,1,0)$ and $(3,1,0,0)$ etc...

Comment: legend thank you for helping i really appreciate it