# Finding bijection between ordered n-tuple of integers and integers

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've got a question for an assignment, but I don't really understand the question. I have however thought of a strategy to solve it. I'm looking for an explanation of the question and feedback on my strategy for finding a bijection.

**Question:**

Let $S = \{(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n)| n \geq 1, a_i \in Z^{\geq 0} \text{ for }  i = 1, 2, . . . , n, a_n \neq 0\}$. Find bijection from set $S$ to set $Z^+$.

What I understand from the question is that $S$ is the set $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)|n \geq 1$ and each element of that set, $a_i$, is an element of $Z^{\geq 0}$, which to me looks like $S=Z$. What I don't understand is what $\text{ for }  i = 1, 2, . . . , n, a_n \neq 0\}$ means and how it relates to the problem.

My strategy for solving this problem is to create a function from $f:S\rightarrow Z^+$ and then to find the inverse function, then use the inverse function to find a bijection for an element of $Z^+$. Is that the best way to solve this?

Also thought about proving the cardinality, $|S|=|Z^+|$, and saying that implies that the sets are bijective, but I don't know if the tutor would accept that.

Comment: What are $Z^+$ and $Z^{\geq 0}$?

Comment: $Z^+$ are non-negative non-zero integers. I'm assuming $Z^{\geq 0}$ is just $Z$.

Comment: $S$ is contained of $n$-tuples for a fixed number $n$, where the first $n-1$ entries are non-negative integers and only the $n$-th entry must be a positive integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a function with a bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363881/defining-a-function-with-a-bijection)

Comment: If you really do require $n\geq 1$, which in the linked question wasn't required, then you can modify the function described there by subtracting one so that you have a preimage for the number $1$ which would have been mapped to by the $0$-tuple $()$.

Comment: Also notice that for $n=1$ you really have $S = Z^+$, but for $ n=2$ you have $S = Z^{\geq 0} \times Z^{+}$ and so forth for bigger $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Finding a function between $S$ and $Z^+$ is not so difficult. But proving that it is bijection will be much more difficult if the map has not been correctly engineered.

A way is to proceed by induction on $n$. For $n=2$, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364771/prove-x-y-mapsto-fracxyxy12y-is-surjective/3364792#3364792) will be useful. Based on the bijection $f$ for $n=2$, you can proceed from $n$ to $n+1$ using

$$f_{n+1}(a_1, \dots ,a_{n+1})=f_2(f_n(a_1, \dots, a_n),a_{n+1})$$

If you know the theorem of Cantor-Bernstein, then finding an injection from $S$ into $Z^+$ and one from $Z^+$ into $S$ will be sufficient.

Injection from $Z^+$ into $S$ is easy...

For an injection from $S$ into $Z^+$ consider $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) =p_1^{a_1}, \dots p_n^{a_n}$ where $p_1,\dots, p_n$ are différent prime integers.